# Managing the deployments of a custom application

Tags: deployment, lamp

My custom app needs things like configuration files with localized constants (sub/domain, api keys, etc.), database config, directory permission set, and others.

I've written a script that reads a JSON object from top to bottom with instructions about what to check, halting the routine if there's something wrong. But I have a feeling that others have a better plan, when it comes to both deploying a custom app to a new server, or rolling out periodic updates for it.

**Some things that might be involved in deploying a custom LAMP application to a new server:**

- checking config files accessibility and completeness of localized constants therein
- checking hardened directory permissions, and writeability for log/upload dirs
- requesting db user, pass, dbname, port, etc. then checking DB connectivity
- creating tables, inserting default data
- presenting a form for "Setup" (such as: enter your desired admin name, password, etc.), validating input and storing it
- checking mail server accessibility

**As an application developer, how do you manage deployment and updating a new server with your applications?**

Some searches I've done in StackOverflow:

- `deployment manager for php application`
- `install utility for setting up and configuring`

Similar, but not the same:

- [PHP Deployment. Configuration Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990264/php-deployment-configuration-step)
- [What is your preferred php deployment strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425692/what-is-your-preferred-php-deployment-strategy)